# NUnit skip save changes

Tags: asp.net, nunit

I'm testing a MVC ASP.Net Web Application and using NUnit to test its controllers. I test the Create method in the controllers and there's a step that it save changes to a stored local database. But NUnit always skips the save changes step. Is there anyway can solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by skipping? Please provide your code as a [mcve] and clearly explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I have uploaded a specific error in an answer

Comment: Oh problems have been solved.

Answer (score -1):

This is the method I coded in the controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CourseId,CourseName,CoursCategoryId,Credit")] COURSE course)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.COURSEs.Add(course);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CourseCategagoryId = new SelectList(db.CourseCategorys, "CourseCategoryId", "CourseCategoryId", course.CourseCategoryId);
        return View(course);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "COURSEs", new { id = 1 });
    }
}
```

And this is the test method I used to test that method

```
[Test]
[TestCase("IT01", "Computer Science", "PRA", 4, "Index")]
public void AddCourseTest(string CourseId, 
    string CourseName, string CourseCategoryId, int Credit, string expected)
{
    COURSE course = new COURSE
    {
        CourseCategoryId= CourseCategoryId,
        CourseName= CourseName,
        CourseCategoryId= CourseCategoryId,
        Credit= Credit
    };
    COURSEsController = new COURSEsController ();
    RedirectToRouteResult result = COURSEsController .Create(course ) as RedirectToRouteResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.RouteValues["action"].ToString());
}
```

As expected that the course I'll add hasn't existed in our database, so the result will redirect to "Index" page. But when I debug the test method, It seems that when it runs to the `db.SaveChanges()`, it threw exceptions and always return to "Create" page.